# Auto Populate a field from one object to another in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm pretty new to writing triggers so please bear with me.

I have two objects (Opportunity Line Item) and (NoticeOfSaleProduct_c). I want to update 2 fields (commision) and (percentage) which are common in both the objects. So if I update these two fields while creating a record in (Opportunity Line Item) object it should populate in (NoticeOfSaleProduct_c) object as well.

Please help

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're new to writing triggers, Trailhead is the best place to get started.

Comment: It would be better to share some code or working that have already be done or see the reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask